# AnythingSlider - link to a certain image in the slider from a different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, anythingslider

I'm using AnythingSlider jQuery plugin for my gallery. What I try to do is - create a link and "link" it to a specific slide on another page's slider.

For example, the link I have on the page gallery.php is:

```
<a href="photo.php?imageID=12345"></a>
```

And my slider itself is on the page photo.php and it does contain that image in one of its slides. I need to show that specific image first in the slider on the page photo.php when it loads.

Does anybody have any clue on how can this be achieved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything slider has this functionality built-in. It updates the URL hash with the current slideshow and slide when you click one of the navigation tabs.

Here is a link to an AnythingSlider demo page, notice when you click on a tab to change the slide that the URL hash changes: http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/

To link to the fourth slide on the first slideshow on the page you would add this to the URL:

```
#panel1-4
```

This option is turned-on by default with the `hashTags` option set to `true`.

Comment: Thanks. But how would my first page know which number that image is in the slider on the other page? I can't hardcode values, I get the images in the gallery dynamically, from DB.

Comment: If you are dynamically building the slideshow, just query the database for the image referenced in your querystring parameter and add it to the slideshow first. Then when you query the database for the rest of the slides, tell it to omit the one you've already added to the slideshow. Otherwise, when building the link to the slideshow, I would make the same database query as the one that populates the slideshow and see what index the requested image is at.

Comment: In the [newest version](https://github.com/ProLoser/AnythingSlider) you can just use the id of the element: [#quote2](http://proloser.github.com/AnythingSlider/demos.html#quote2)